# How to pass scope name to lerna command dynamic?

Tags: javascript, bash, yarnpkg, lerna

I use lerna to manage projects and `dev` command exists in some projects.
For exmaple, A and B have command `dev` to start project.
I must write two command in root project:

```json
{
 "dev:A":"lerna exec --scope A -- yarn dev",
 "dev:B":"lerna exec --scope B -- yarn dev"
}
```

It's there anyway to run like this:

```sh
yarn dev A
```

I try but it's failure. The scope name is pass to yarn dev not lerna.

```json
{
 "dev":"lerna exec --scope $1 -- yarn dev",
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Forget it.
I see the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48169878/pass-args-into-lerna-exec-command) and the command  `"lerna exec 'yarn dev' --scope"` works.

Answer (score 0):

The executable is not yarn, but lerna. You want the command to be

```sh
lerna run dev --scope xyz
```

So either install it globally and call it like that, or install it as a project dependency and then

```sh
yarn lerna -- run dev --scope ...
# or 
`npm run lerna -- run dev --scope ...`
```

or use `npx lerna run dev --scope ...` to run it globally without explicit install.

Why that way?

Because `yarn <bin>`/`npm run <bin>` executes the bin as if you'd call it directly, and the `--` seperates arguments to yarn/npm from arguments to the bin you called. More recent yarns will allow you to drop the `--` and figure them out automagically.

I'm not sure if you really need to use `yarn dev` instead of simply `dev` in the lerna part of the script, as lerna does just that -- walk all projects, look up if any project has a `dev` script and executes it (if you use `--scope`, it will of course only look up the given project(s)...). You might need it with yarn less it calls the commands in the sub-packages using `npm` instead, but I didn't check that, as our company uses npm.

A package.json including

```json
{
  "scripts": { "dev": "lerna run dev --scope x" }
}
```

does the same thing if you launch it with `yarn dev`.

If you want to call the lerna-dev script with more arguments, you can always go for `yarn dev -- --include-dependencies` in the terminal, which will append all arguments after `dev` to `lerna` instead of yarn, in this example resulting in `yarn lerna -- dev --scope x --include-dependencies`